# Is there always exists a product over a semigroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, direct-sum, semigroups, direct-product

Let $(S,+)$ a semigroup, is there exists a product over $S$, i.e., a binary operation $\cdot$ over $S$ such that $$ x\cdot(y+z)= x \cdot y + x \cdot z,\, (y+z)\cdot x = y\cdot x + z\cdot x,\, x\cdot(y\cdot z) = (x\cdot y)\cdot z$$
for all $x,y,z \in S$ ?

For example, for any finitely abelian group $G$, we know for the fundamental theorem of abelian groups that $G$ is isomorphic to a direct sum $\mathbb{Z}^n \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p_1} \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p_k}$, where $n,k \geq 0$ and $p_i$ is a prime tower. We can see each one of these groups as a ring under the usual product for $\mathbb{Z}$ and product mod $(p_i)$ for $\mathbb{Z}_{p_i}$, so this direct sum can be seen as a product ring, with $G$ as the underlying abelian group.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming monoid $M$ is commutative with its operation denoted $+$, there is always the trivial product defined by $x \cdot y=0$ for all $x,y \in M$ [where $0$ is the additive identity of $M$ where the commutative monoid $M$ is written in additive notation.] This satisfies the rules you mention, but isn't a very interesting product to say the least. Note this construction works for any abelian monoid, finite or not.

Added later: As I noted in a comment one does not need to assume monoid $M$ is commutative. At the time I wasn't sure and asked for someone to check, which @J.-E. Pin has done.

Comment: Thanks, I knew this particular, though.

Comment: You should edit your answer again. What you really need is that $G$ is a commutative monoid (and $M$ might be a more suggestive notation than $G$ or $S$).

Comment: Thanks @J.-E.Pin will do as you suggest.

Comment: I approve Pin's edit but couldn't get to someplace other to officially register the approval.

Comment: Looking at it later one may not really need the monoid to be commutative. If someone could check that and see, I could add that to the answer [with a citation for whoever checked it].

Comment: @coffeemath You are right. Perhaps my example skewed you answer.

Comment: I think what J.-E.-Pin had in mind when he said it should be a commutative monoid, was that that is necessary to get a ring. If the goal is just to satisfy the displayed equations, commutativity is not necessary, since with the null product they all resume to the trivial $0=0$. Notice there is a 'ring-theory' tag, and as Jose put it in a comment, his example may have skewed the ideas.